# Service Wont Stop

Tags: android, android-service

I have a Switch that turns the service on and off.
The problem is it won't turn the service off and I don't know why,
the service implements the SensorEventListener and the idea is that the app will detect movements of the phone without being inside the app.

But the off switch won't work.
Any ideas why the service won't stop?

The Service:

```
public class MyService extends Service implements SensorEventListener {

    private Sensor accelerometer;
    private SensorManager sm;
    private Float MinFallValue,MaxFallValue;

    public FallDetectorService() {
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i("LocalService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);
        sm=(SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        accelerometer = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        sm.registerListener(this, accelerometer,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.values[2] < MinFallValue)){
           // Do something
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }
}
```

The MainActivity:

```
Switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if(isChecked){
            Toast.makeText(SettingActivity.this, "Starting service", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(SettingActivity.this, MyService.class);
            startService(intent);
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(SettingActivity.this,"Stoping service",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(SettingActivity.this, MyService.class);
            stopService(intent);
        }
    }
});
```